# Is it ok to extend a function constructor?

Tags: javascript

I'm extending a function to add more static methods and properties.

Is it ok to extend a function constructor?

```
class ExtendedFunction extends Function {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
  }
  
  static myName() {
    return `My Name is ${this.name}`;
  }
}

console.log(ExtendedFunction.myName())
```

**Also is it possible to extend a function as a function instead of a class?**

Comment: This is clearly an XY problem, you assumed that this solves a problem for you and asked if this can work, instead of directly talking about the problem you're facing and this should be it's solution

Comment: Depends on how you're going to be calling this. Currently, your constructor is not accepting any parameters, so it's kind of making quite a useless custom `Function` object. With that said, though you *should be* avoiding calling the `Function` constructor anyway. Dynamically evaluating code is fraught with perils. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) what are you actually doing that extending `Function` solves?